# absolute positioning not working proper in IE, but it works ok in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-position

Here is [my page](https://www.sanshinj.co.jp/manufacture/) and codes:

```css
.col-md-6 {
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
}
.headqt-corner-blk img{
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
.h-corner-ctn {
  padding: 5px;
}
.h-corner-ctn-relative {
    position: relative;
}
.h-corner-text-absolute{
  position: absolute;
  left: -115px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="headqt-corner-blk">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="h-corner-ctn">
                        <img src="https://www.sanshinj.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/headqt-page-pro-1.jpg" alt="パートナーを募集しています">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="h-corner-ctn">
                        <img src="https://www.sanshinj.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/headqt-page-pro-2.png" alt="パートナーを募集しています">
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="h-corner-ctn">
                        <img src="https://www.sanshinj.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/headqt-page-pro-3.png" alt="パートナーを募集しています">
                
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="h-corner-ctn h-corner-ctn-relative">
                    <div class="h-corner-text-absolute">
                     <h4 class="corner-ttl"> 協力会社の募集
</h4>
                     <p>三進工業では、私たちと一緒にプラント工事に従事する協力会社を募集しています。詳しくはこちらからご確認ください。</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

It works in Chrome and Firefox, but when I tested it on IE, it didn't work as I aspect. It moves to the left -115px but it also aligns right 115px, I want the position fixed at the right side. 
See it in detail at these pictures:
[Error happens in IE browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTP0g.jpg)
[Chrome and Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJTg6.jpg)

Comment: If that is your actual html then you haven't applied the styles properly, if not then please create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem

Comment: Please add proper code so we can help you. the one you added is not with inline style and the css class which you are not using.

Comment: @Pete , Sumit: My page is created by Elementor Wordpress, if I change the Elementor's value the CSS will change. Coud you detect it in my actual code on this part? https://www.sanshinj.co.jp/manufacture/#absolute-detect

Comment: @Tam.Phan, you need to create a [mcve] with your rendered html in the question itself otherwise the question is off topic for SO - please read: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: @Pete, yeah, thank you. I'm going to create my demonstrating codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that as soon as you will specificy a width in percentage on an absolute element, it will refer to the first relative parent element, or, if not defined, to the width of your page.

This beeing said, your HTML has indeed a parent relative element which width is smaller than the expected result.

Here, you want to shift your element by 115px on the left, but you also want to enlarge the size of your element by 115px as well.
You will need to refine the width by this additional offset. You need to refine the max-width as well, as currently set to 100%.

Below is the CSS that will work on all web browsers

```
.absolute{
   left: -115px;
   top: 10px;
   position: absolute;
   width: calc(100% + 115px);
   max-width: calc(100% + 115px);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I wanted to define.